# php: Use case for break(n) and continue(n)?

Tags: php

I'm reading "Programming PHP" and came across the break(n) and continue(n) statements.

break(n) I guess I could see some use for, but continue(n) blew my mind- when would you use that? The example in the book for continue(n) is totally arbitrary and it doesn't even bother to propose a real world example of where its use is advantageous.

Also, I have read you should you always try to avoid breaking out of multiple loops like this anyway. Is this just for readability or are there performance or other issues this might cause?

edit: Maybe I wasn't clear with my question. I understand what the break and continue statements do, my question is when you would use the php feature that allows you to break or continue out of multiple loops in a _real_world_ situation. Meaning are there any common patterns I would see in wild that use these features?  Are there problems that arise in the php language requiring the novelty of break(n) and continue(n)? I only ask because I have not seen this feature in other languages and thought maybe php had some special use cases for them other languages would not.

Comment: Just because you cannot conceive of a situation where something might be useful does not mean that it is useless. Producing readable, concise code would ostensibly be the point of breaking/continuing out of more than one loop with a single statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you're searching a 3-dimensional array using 3 nested loops.

With `break(n)`:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
  for($j=0; $j<count($arr[$i]); $j++) {
    for($k=0; $k<count($arr[$i][$j]); $k++) {
      if( $some_condition == 'satisfied')
        break 3;
    }
  }
}
```

Without:

```
$found = false;
for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
  for($j=0; $j<count($arr[$i]); $j++) {
    for($k=0; $k<count($arr[$i][$j]); $k++) {
      if( $some_condition == 'satisfied')
        $found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if($found) break;
  }
  if($found) break;
}
```

and consider the case that you might have an obscure condition where you only want to break/continue out of the inner 2 loops, but not the outer loop, or a tree-like structure of nested loops. Without `break(n)/continue(n)` your code could become bloated and confusing.

That said, no one's going to *force* you to use it. Chill out. PHP has *many* more even *less* useful things built into it than multi-level break/continue.

Answer (score 2):

Break literally breaks exexution for loop. Continue continues to the next iteration.

For example you want do stuff until something comes up. Then use break if you want to end whole loop.

If you want to skip iteration to the next one for some reason, use continue.

Answer (score 0):

There are many use-cases for each, the most obvious for break is with the switch statement:

```
switch($var) {
    case 1: do_something(); break;
    case 2: do_something_else(); break;
}
```

Without the break, then whenever $var = 1, then do_something() will be called and the execution will not leave the switch statement (causing do_something_else() to also be called).

The continue statement can be used in a loop if there are iterations you want to skip:

```
foreach($arr as $entry) {
    if(!isset($entry['key'])) {
        continue;
    }
    do_something($entry['key']);
}
```

That of course is a pretty contrived example, but hopefully you get the jist.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have some nested loops like this

```
for($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
    for { $y = 0; $y < 10; $y++) {
        // will step into the next loop of the inner for
        // continue;

        // will step to the next loop of the outer for
        // continue 2;
    }
}
```

The same rules applying for `break`. It will either break the inner, the outer or even more nested loops depending on it's usage.

Comment: No idea why you're getting voted down here. Have an upvote instead!

Comment: I also don't see a reason. the example should be ok. thank you :)

Comment: I didn't downvote - but you aren't actually answering the question. He is asking for real world examples of why it might be useful - not what it actually does.

Comment: @TimB I can't see any real world example on this page.

Comment: The 3d array is the only one. As I said I didn't downvote you - if I had I'd have downvoted the other two miss-answers too.

Comment: However, I can live with the shame ;)